# Adding to a User Input Variable

Tags: java, class, variables, input, methods

I'm new to Java and having a little trouble getting the concept of Java. One of my class assignments is to create two class and have one for the output and one for the input. Otherwise known as an instance and driver class.

So if I have something like
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
** Declare it **

System.out.println("How many do you have?");
int count = userInput.nextInt();

Then, I need to put arithmetic into a new method. Then that new method needs to be called inside the other class how would I do so?

When I try count = count + 5;

It just says I have a duplicate variable.

https://gyazo.com/f9b008d839ecfad6d9ef33334a47782a
https://gyazo.com/6a420e98e27fa8779fec4ccab158f9bc

Comment: Show us the _complete_ code you have so far, and refer to the two classes by name. Your question is a tad confusing/unspecific

Comment: Your question is not clear,also please provide the code for the classes and specify where exactly is your problem , we can't just imagin what your classes look like

Comment: Terribly sorry about that I have a Gyazo screenshots edited to the post.

Comment: Fixed @qxz sorry for the inconvenience. .

Comment: You need to put the code in the code snippet not in images mate

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Instance
{
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

void show()
{
    System.out.println("How many do you have?");
    int count = userInput.nextInt();
    count=count+5;
    System.out.println(count);

 }
```

}

class Driver
    {
       Instance instance = new Instance();
       B()
       {
         instance.show();
       }
}

class Result
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Driver d =new Driver();
    }
}

Comment: why you adding `Scanner` at **Class** level?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever.